# Receiving "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error when passing a string between classes using Sub (VB)

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to pass string through a function that's defined in another class but receiving the error in the title.

Code definition:

```
Public Class frmStudentTrackers

    Public Sub errorMessage(ByVal detail As String)
        MessageBox.Show(detail, "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Error Message implementation:

```
Public Class Student

    Public mainform As frmStudentTrackers
    Public totalTestCompleted As Integer
    Public AllTests(7) As String

    Public Function getTestResults(ByRef totalTestsCompleted As Integer)
        totalTestCompleted = 0
        Dim arrayPos As Integer = 0
        Dim testNumber As Integer = 1

        For i = 0 To 7
            AllTests(arrayPos) = InputBox("Please Enter the result for test " & testNumber & Environment.NewLine & "Please enter True (Pass), False (Fail) Or N/A if not completed!", "Test Result Collection")
            AllTests(arrayPos) = StrConv(AllTests(arrayPos), vbUpperCase)
            If AllTests(arrayPos) = "TRUE" Or AllTests(arrayPos) = "FALSE" Then
                totalTestCompleted = totalTestCompleted + 1
            ElseIf AllTests(arrayPos) <> "TRUE" Or AllTests(arrayPos) <> "FALSE" Or AllTests(arrayPos) <> "N/A" Then
                mainform.errorMessage("This is not a valid option! The test result input will now restart. Please begin from test 1, inputing True (Pass), False (Fail) Or N/A if not completed!")
                End
            End If
            arrayPos = arrayPos + 1
            testNumber = testNumber + 1
        Next
        Return totalTestCompleted
    End Function

End Class
```

I made a document to test it so if you need the full program, let me know and I can put it here for you!
My aim is to get what's in the brackets (passed as detail) to the function, so an error message can appear. I understand the error is because the value is apparently null even though I've defined it?
Is there something I'm doing wrong?

I hope that makes sense! Thank you!

Comment: When I do that (at the top of the students class) the program won't run and I'm receiving a System.StackoverflowException error? Would I need to declare it inside the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to instance your class, not only declaring it.

Instead of doing this: `Public mainform As frmStudentTrackers` try doing this:

`Public mainform As New frmStudentTrackers`

Comment: Thank you! I put realised I needed to put it into the function too! It's working now! Thank you so much! But for some reason, strconv won't convert "n/a" to uppercase?

Comment: Does it work with "true" and "false" and not with "n/a"?

Comment: yeah it does, i added a breakpoint and for some reason, it just won't work with "n/a"

Comment: I can only think that is somehow related to the "/" character that is being added, but I have tried it myself and it works just fine with a string that contains "n/a"

Comment: That was my initial thought to! For some reason, when I enter "n/a" or "N/A" I get the error message?

Comment: I think I fixed it! I changed all the `or`s in `ElseIf AllTests(arrayPos) <> "TRUE" Or AllTests(arrayPos) <> "FALSE" Or AllTests(arrayPos) <> "N/A" Then` to `and`. It seems to work? Idk why it was showing as not being in uppercase though